# How to convert UST to EST in Azure data factory mapping data flows?

Tags: azure-data-factory

1.How to convert UST to EST in mapping data flows in azure data factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [fromUTC()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#fromutc) and supplement `America/New_York` as the second parameter if your input column is already a timestamp type.

[image]

For eastern time reference, please check out [this article](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/convert-date-time-to-est-est5edt/) about java timezone.

Comment: Coordinated Universal Time is 4 hours ahead of Eastern Time

Comment: it's not working as Coordinated Universal Time is 4 hours ahead of Eastern Time but the ouptust is shwoing as five hours difference

Comment: @Venkatesh sorry for the mistake. I have correct the solution to use `America/New_York` instead of `EST`. Please see if that helps.

Comment: I request you to please mark the answer as accepted if it resolved your issue (click on check mark on left side of answer). This will help other community members.